# How to get canvas element co-ordinates from chrome browser

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, html5-canvas, gojs

I did try with many chrome extension but seems it is counting co-ordinates from top of the window rather than only consider canvas.

I am on this page: https://gojs.net/latest/samples/grouping.html

want to get co-ordinate of below + button :

[image]

I am actully trying to click on that + button using selenium using action class , my code is :

```
  driver.get("https://gojs.net/latest/samples/grouping.html");
        WebElement flowCanvas = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='myDiagramDiv']//canvas"));

            new Actions(driver)
                    .moveToElement(flowCanvas, 500, 200).click().perform();
```

Because I am not getting exact co-ordinates of + button, above code, is not clicking on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume the `500, 200` values are an (x,y) point in the coordinate system of your `flowCanvas` HTML element.  Is that correct?

First, you'll need to get to the **Diagram** object that your app creates for the HTMLDivElement that holds the canvas(es) and other elements used by GoJS to show the diagram and support editing.  Call the static function **[Diagram.fromDiv](https://gojs.net/latest/api/symbols/Diagram.html#static-fromDiv)** for that.  For example:

```
var myDiagram = go.Diagram.fromDiv(theDivElement);
```

Then you need to know the key of the **Group** whose button you want to click.  If the "SubGraphExpanderButton" in the **Group** template has a **GraphObject.name** and you know what the name is, you could do something like:

```
var group = myDiagram.findNodeForKey(groupKey);
if (!group) return;
var button = group.findObject(buttonName);
if (!button) return;
var docpt = button.getDocumentPoint(go.Spot.Center);
var viewpt = myDiagram.transformDocToView(docpt);
new Actions(driver)
    .moveToElement(flowCanvas, viewpt.x, viewpt.y)
    .click()
    .perform();
```

This is the same technique demonstrated in the Robot sample:
https://gojs.net/latest/extensions/Robot.html

Hmmm, you might want to make sure that the node (or at least the button) is within the viewport first.  Call **[Diagram.scrollToRect](https://gojs.net/latest/api/symbols/Diagram.html#scrollToRect)** first.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Here the issue is how can I get the support of myDiagram in my code. Mainly I am using java here and I tried to use myDiagram with javascipt but did not work. Is there any file I need to import or and maven dependency if I want to get support of all inbuild libraries of goJs in Java?

Comment: I've added a paragraph to my answer, above.  I would expect that you should be able to find the HTML Div element one way or another.  How that is may depend a lot on which framework your app is using, if any.

Comment: By the way, it would be better not to get a reference to the HTMLCanvasElement that may be within the HTMLDivElement. The implementation of GoJS may change how many canvases there are and even whether there is a canvas element at all.